# White border on both sides of the image

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm trying to load my my image to a custom view but after loading im getting withite border on both sides.

[image]

My custom imageView

#### MyCanvas

```
public class MyCanvas extends ImageView {
private Paint mPaint;
private Path mPath;
private Map<Path, Integer> mPaths;
private PathsChangedListener mListener;

private int mColor;
private float mCurX;
private float mCurY;
private float mStartX;
private float mStartY;
private boolean mPaintIsOn;
private Activity mScaleDetector;
private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;

public void setmPaintIsOn(boolean mPaintIsOn) {
    this.mPaintIsOn = mPaintIsOn;
}

public MyCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    mPath = new Path();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    mPaths = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    mPaths.put(mPath, mPaint.getColor());
    pathsUpdated();
}

public void setListener(PathsChangedListener listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
}

public void undo() {
    if (mPaths.size() <= 0)
        return;

    Path lastKey = null;
    for (Path key : mPaths.keySet()) {
        lastKey = key;
    }

    mPaths.remove(lastKey);
    pathsUpdated();
    invalidate();
}

public void setColor(int newColor) {
    mColor = newColor;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (mPaintIsOn) {

        for (Map.Entry<Path, Integer> entry : mPaths.entrySet()) {
            mPaint.setColor(entry.getValue());
            canvas.drawPath(entry.getKey(), mPaint);
        }

        mPaint.setColor(mColor);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}

public void clearCanvas(){
    mPath.reset();
    mPaths.clear();
    pathsUpdated();
    invalidate();
}

private void actionDown(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mCurX = x;
    mCurY = y;
}

private void actionMove(float x, float y) {
    mPath.quadTo(mCurX, mCurY, (x + mCurX) / 2, (y + mCurY) / 2);
    mCurX = x;
    mCurY = y;
}

private void actionUp() {
    mPath.lineTo(mCurX, mCurY);

    // draw a dot on click
    if (mStartX == mCurX && mStartY == mCurY) {
        mPath.lineTo(mCurX, mCurY + 2);
        mPath.lineTo(mCurX + 1, mCurY + 2);
        mPath.lineTo(mCurX + 1, mCurY);
    }

    mPaths.put(mPath, mPaint.getColor());
    pathsUpdated();
    mPath = new Path();
}

private void pathsUpdated() {
    if (mListener != null && mPaths != null) {
        mListener.pathsChanged(mPaths.size());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    final MotionEvent event = ev;
    if (mPaintIsOn) {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mStartX = x;
                mStartY = y;
                actionDown(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                actionMove(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                actionUp();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

   return true;
}

public interface PathsChangedListener {
    void pathsChanged(int cnt);
}
```

Over here im trying to draw on image with different colors.

my method which loads image to MyCanvas imageview

```
private void setPreviewImage(final Bitmap bmp) {
    if (bmp != null) {
        mCanvas.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

The xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<a9msquare.mustache.Views.MyCanvas
    android:id="@+id/my_canvas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/color_picker"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/undo"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/color_picker"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not exactly a white border, the image you are setting in your custom view is not of exactly the same size as your `MyCanvas` view. You will need to scale or crop your image if you want it to take up all the space without leaving any empty spaces around.

Try adding `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your `MyCanvas` in your layout.xml. Your `MyCanvas` would look like:

```
<a9msquare.mustache.Views.MyCanvas
    android:id="@+id/my_canvas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```